# os.system command to call shell script with arguments

Tags: python, shell, arguments, os.system

I am writing a python script which uses `os.system` command to call a shell script.I need help understanding how I can pass the arguments to the shell script? Below is what I am trying..but it wouldn't work.

```
os.system('./script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3')
```

I do not want to use `subprocess` for calling the shell script. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the subprocess module?

Comment: Second that why not use subprocess?

Comment: Also, when you say it doesn't work, how do you know it's not working?  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Place your script and it's args into a string, see example below.

HTH

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

arg3 = 'arg3'
cmd = '/bin/echo arg1 arg2 %s' % arg3

print 'running "%s"' % cmd

os.system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert the following line before os.system (...), you will likely see your problem.

`print './script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3'`

When developing this type of thing, it usually is useful to make sure the command really is what you expect, before you actually try it.

example:

```
def Cmd():
    return "something"

print Cmd()
```

when you are satisfied, comment out the `print Cmd()` line and use `os.system (Cmd ())` or subprocess version.